# How to write a comparator function for qsort for a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, comparator, qsort

I have an n*2 sized array. I want to sort them using qsort based on their value of the 2nd column.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int cmp(const int **a, const int **b) {
    //return 0;
    //return *a[1] - *b[1]
    // return *a - *b;
}
int main()
{
    int t; // test cases
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)  {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n); // size of array
        int **arr = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *)); 

        for(int j =0; j< n; j++) {
            arr[j] = (int *) malloc(2*sizeof(int));
        }
        for(int j =0; j< 2; j++) {
            for(int k =0; k< n; k++) {
              scanf("%d", &arr[k][j]);
            }
        }
        for(int k =0; k< n; k++) {
            for(int j =0; j<= 1; j++) {
             printf("%d\t", arr[k][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
       // qsort(arr, n, sizeof(arr[0]), cmp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So for input,

```
1 2 
3 6 
0 8 
5 4 
8 9 
5 7
```

Output is,

```
1 2
5 4
3 6
5 7
0 8
8 9
```

I tried but couldn't sort them according to their 2nd column. I am confused with passing array element to the comparator. Also with what to pass as the size of the element? But I guess that first 2 among below are correct.

```
qsort(arr, n, sizeof(arr[0]), cmp);
//qsort(arr, n, sizeof((int *)), cmp);
//qsort(arr, n, 2 * sizeof((int)), cmp);
```

I tried various combinations for the comparator.

Please hint out the way or perhaps an explanation.

Comment: I don't have at all the same output than you.

Comment: @Stargateur. I don't have any output at all, I have just printed the input. I am yet to sort the array to get an output. I just need help with the comparator function.

Comment: I don't see why someone downvoted it, a reason would be nice. It isn't that I haven't tried or done some research.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question but maybe I should as I say the output you claim your program has is wrong, and it's not clear what you trying to do with your code. There are already ton of question that show exemple of use of qsort, even in the documentation !

Comment: "*what to pass as the size of the element?*" Hint: In C a 2D array in fact is a 1D array of 1D arrays.

Comment: @Stargateur. I am stuck in the part where I need to sort the array , according to the 2nd Columns as the array has n rows and 2 columns. I just need help to write a comparator. That's it. You might have noticed that the qsort is commented. I will print the sorted result afterward. So all I want is a way to access elements in the cmp function, which I am not able to. Also whats wrong with the expected ouput?

Comment: @alk. Yes I know that. But I was confused if I shall pass the size of pointer which points to a row or actual size of row i.e, 2* int_size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prototype for the comparison function is specified in the prototype for the `qsort` function:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
           int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

Your comparison function must be compatible, so you can define it this way:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    /* a and b are pointers to the array of pointers. */
    int *aa = *(int * const *)a;
    int *bb = *(int * const *)b;
    return (aa[1] > bb[1]) - (aa[1] < bb[1]);
}
```

Or without casts:

```
int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    /* a and b are pointers to the array of pointers. */
    int * const *aa = a;
    int * const *bb = b;
    int ia = (*aa)[1];
    int ib = (*bb)[1];
    return (ia > ib) - (ia < ib);
}
```

Note that you cannot use the simplistic comparison `aa[1] - bb[1]` as it can overflow for large values and at best produce incorrect output.

Furthermore, you input loop is incorrect: you should nest the loops in the opposite order:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
           scanf("%d", &arr[k][j]);
        }
    }
```

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    /* a and b are pointers to the array of pointers. */
    int * const *aa = a;
    int * const *bb = b;
    int ia = (*aa)[1];
    int ib = (*bb)[1];
    return (ia > ib) - (ia < ib);
}

int main() {
    int t; // test cases
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n); // size of array
        int **arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            arr[j] = malloc(sizeof(*arr[j]) * 2);
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                scanf("%d", &arr[k][j]);
            }
        }
        qsort(arr, n, sizeof(arr[0]), cmp);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                printf("%d\t", arr[k][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            free(arr[j]);
        }
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can also simplify the code using an actual 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    return (aa[1] > bb[1]) - (aa[1] < bb[1]);
}

int main() {
    int t; // test cases
    scanf("%d", &t);
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n); // size of array
        int (*arr)[2] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);

        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            scanf("%d%d", &arr[k][0], &arr[k][1]);
        }
        qsort(arr, n, sizeof(arr[0]), cmp);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            printf("%d\t%d\n", arr[k][0], arr[k][1]);
        }
        free(arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean `int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)` right?

Comment: @chqrlie. I know what `const int *a` mean but what does this mean, `*(const int * const *)a` ?

Comment: @SatishKumar: `const int * const *` is the type of a constant pointer to an array of constant pointers to arrays of `int`. The first `const` is actually useless and I shall remove it, the second one is there to avoid a compiler warning if a were to convert a constant pointer `const void *` to a non constant pointer `int **`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: of course, my initial post was bogus.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you don't have a 2D array. You have a 1D array of pointers that each points to a 1D array of `int`.

So what you can do is to sort the 1D array of pointers. For that you can write a compare function that looks at the value of the pointed-to element.

It could look something like:

```
int cmp(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    int* const * x = a;
    int* const * y = b;
    if ((*x)[1] < (*y)[1]) return -1;
    if ((*x)[1] > (*y)[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

As said above: It's the array of pointers that is sorted. You can visualize it like:

[image]

Comment: The 1st `const`s (from the left) are not necessary.

Comment: What does this mean, `const int* const * x = a;` ? Is this the same as typecasting x(const) to int

Comment: @SatishKumar  It means: "declare x as pointer to const pointer to int" and initialize it to the value a. It's need for converting the void-pointer into a pointer that you can dereference.