# Problem with my quicksort, it doesn't sort correctly

Tags: c++, quicksort

OK I am trying to make Prima algorithm so i need my edges array sorted, I tried to use quicksort here but it didn't work as I planned.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

void Sort (int arr[100][4], int m, int l) {
     int i,j,x,v;

    i=m;
    j=l;
    x=(i+j)/2;
    do
    {
        while (((arr[i][3]<arr[x][3]))and(i<=l)) i++;
        while (((arr[j][3]>arr[x][3]))and(j>=m)) j--;
        if (i<=j)
        {
        v=arr[i][1];
        arr[i][1]=arr[j][1];
        arr[j][1]=v;
        v=arr[i][2];
        arr[i][2]=arr[j][2];
        arr[j][2]=v;
        v=arr[i][3];
        arr[i][3]=arr[j][3];
        arr[j][3]=v;
        i++;
        j--;
        }
    }
    while (i<=j);
    if (i<l) Sort(arr,i,l);
    if (m<j) Sort(arr,m,j);
}

int main () {
    int i,x,y,z,n,m;
    int a[100][4];
    fill(&a[0][0],&a[0][0]+400,0);
    cout<<"Enter number of nodes and edges\n";
    cin>>n>>m;
    cout<<"Enter edges and their weights\n";
    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        cin>>x>>y>>z;
        a[i][1]=min(x,y);
        a[i][2]=max(x,y);
        a[i][3]=z;
        }
    Sort (a,0,m-1);
    for (i=0;i<m;i++) {
        cout<<i+1<<") "<<a[i][1]<<' '<<a[i][2]<<' '<<a[i][3]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

what I put is

5 10

1 2 4

1 3 7

4 1 5

5 1 8

2 3 3

2 4 6

2 5 6

3 4 8

3 5 2

4 5 4

what I get is 
1) 3 5 2

2) 2 3 3

3) 1 4 5

4) 1 2 4

5) 4 5 4

6) 2 5 6

7) 2 4 6

8) 1 3 7

9) 1 5 8

10) 3 4 8

I don't understand why 5 is going ahead of 4's. Hope you could help.

Comment: Why don't you use library qsort.

Comment: @Yogesh I wasn't sure how should it work with multidim. array, also I was sure in my one...

Comment: @Yogesh suggesting `qsort` for a question that is tagged with [tag:c++] is not really helpful. However, you maybe want to use `std::sort`

Comment: @Неизвестный Неизвестный about not being sure how to use it, you can write your own comparator functions which will be used to compare two elements, pass the pointers to multidimentional array and access in the way you want to - for comparisons. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084423/how-to-write-a-comparator-function-for-qsort-for-a-2d-array.
Kudos to your spirit for writing on your own.

Comment: @datell yeah, kind of missed it.

Comment: @Yogesh ok I will try it, but I never worked with comparators and so on, aaand I am really eager to know what's wrong with my algorithm :(

Answer (score 0):

You choose the pivot element in the middle of the (sub)array, which is fine, but *you leave it in that position* when you run the partitioning loop, and rely on it to *stay* there, which is not ok.  With your approach, the pivot is likely to be swapped to a different position during the ordinary course of partitioning, after which the remainder of the partitioning will be based on the key swapped into the pivot's original position, which is likely to be different.

The usual approach is to start by swapping the pivot element to one end of the array or the other, partition the rest of the array, and then afterward swap the pivot into its correct position, as discovered via the partitioning process.

Comment: There's no need to swap the pivot element to one end of the array or the other if using [Hoare partition scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). Instead the issue is that the pivot value (not the index) should be stored in a temp variable.

Comment: @rcgldr, I did not say that it was obligatory to swap the pivot to one end, I said it was *usual*.  There are certainly other alternatives.

Comment: The OP's code is a variation of Hoare partition scheme, where the value of the middle element is used as the pivot, and the pivot is not moved. Elements equal to the pivot value may end up in either partition.

Comment: Well no, @rcgldr, the OP's partitioning scheme is a *broken* variation on Hoare paritioning with the pivot taken as the (initial) middle element.  In particular, it is the combination of leaving the pivot in its original place and relying upon it to stay there that is broken, not the former by itself.  I assert again that the *usual* approach, as in the one I see most often and that seems most common, is the one I've described. It is indeed a perfectly valid implementation of Hoare partitioning, but of course not the only valid one.

Comment: Yes, the OP's code is broken, as it should be using a pivot value, not a pivot index, but I haven't seen any examples of Hoare partition scheme that move the pivot from the middle to either end. Most of them are similar to the one in the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme). Lomuto partition schemes do use either end as the pivot location, or swap the pivot to either end, then swap again to correct pivot location when partition step is done. Hoare may leave elements equal to pivot in either partition.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to use the pivot value instead of the pivot index, and some fixes to make it more like conventional Hoare partition scheme:

```
    i=m-1;
    j=l+1;
    x=arr[(i+j)/2][3];
    while(1)
    {
        while (arr[++i][3] < x);
        while (arr[--j][3] > x);
        if(i >= j)
            return j;
        // ...
```